# ¿Eliminar espacio en un ventana modal en Angular?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, angular

Buenos dias tengo la siguiente duda, estoy trabajando con angular y trabajando con ventanas modales, la cuestion es que no puedo eliminar un espacio que se me presenta al final de la ventana modal, le doy a los estilos CSS y nada, lo voy a dejar señalado en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El espacio señalado es el que quiero eliminar.

Dejos mis codigos:

component.html

```
<mat-toolbar class="bx">
  <span>{{PrtgServiceForm.InterfaceForm.controls['id_puerto'].value > existingId.length?"Nuevo Puerto":"Modificar Puerto"}}</span>
  <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span> 
 <button  id ="bc" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" mat-stroked-button (click)="onClose()" tabIndex="-1">X</button>
</mat-toolbar> 

<form [formGroup]="PrtgServiceForm.InterfaceForm" class="normal-form" (submit)="onSubmit()">  
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="300px">    
           <div class="controles-container">
              <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput formControlName="id_puerto" matInput placeholder="ID Puerto*" readonly>
                  <mat-error>Este Campo es Requerido</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field> 
              <mat-form-field>
                  <input formControlName="nombre" matInput placeholder="Nombre del Puerto*">
                  <mat-error>Este Campo es Requerido</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div class="button-row">
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)=onSubmit() [disabled]="PrtgServiceForm.InterfaceForm.invalid">Guardar</button>&nbsp; 
                  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClear()">Borrar</button>
              </div>
           </div>        
   </mat-grid-list>
 </form>
```

component.css

```
#bc {                       
    /* margin-left: 630px;  */
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 0px !important;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

div.container{
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* Estilos CSS para las entradas de datos */
.controles-container > *{          
    margin: 2px;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 2px;
    justify-content: center
}

/* Estilos CSS para los botones de Guardar y Borrar */
.button-row button{              
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    } 

/* Estilos CSS para el formulario */
form.normal-form{
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 70px ;
    padding: 2px;
    justify-content: center
} 

span {
    font-weight:bold;
} 

.fill-remaining-space {
    /* This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox. 
       Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout. */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

mat-toolbar {
    height: 50px;    
}
```

¿Como podria eliminar ese espacio vacio? Si no hay una etiqueta o elemento como tal en ese espacio

Comment: ¿Podría ser el `<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="300px">`? Tiene pinta de que los 300px son lo que te está generando ese espacio en blanco.

Comment: Lo acabo de quitar y sigue el mismo espacio.

Comment: Ajusta el tamaño de tu modal al contenido que estas utilizando, todo eso es el tamaño del modal, metele css al modal.

Comment: Debuggea todo con chrome en el inspector.

Comment: Ese height seguro es del modal por defecto.

Comment: Usa el inspector de código de tu navegador para encontrar el elemento que te está generando ese espacio.